# How to completely remove a game controller driver?

Tags: drivers, windows-8.1, ps3, game-controller, hid

Ages ago I plugged a fake PS3 controller which installed a Plug-And-Play driver labeled as "PLAYSTATION(R)3Conteroller", yup, including the typo.

Now whenever I connect an original controller this fake driver takes it's place, making it impossible to work properly.

If I uninstall this driver in the "Device Manager" there's no "Delete" option and it will come back to life once I reconnect the controller. If I uninstall and manually delete the driver files (hidclass.sys, hidparse.sys and hidusb.sys) they will still return when the controller is connected again.

In the Device Manager it shows up as "HID-compliant game controller".

Thank you

OS: Windows 8.1 Pro x64

**Screenshots:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [Device Remover](http://www.pro-it-education.de/software/deviceremover/) I was able to get rid of the fake driver completely, afterwards I installed the correct driver.

Comment: How did you remove it? I've downloaded and installed the software, and deleted the device using it, it doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Did you unplug the device and disabled the driver?

Right clicking on the device with Device Remover gives you lots of options, including a driver update, which can be used to manually replace the driver. Also check for duplicated driver names and remove them.

Comment: Yes, did both of that. The issue is I don't have the driver files myself but scpserver detects the default device and installs it. However, the default device is incorrect (still leftover from motioninjoy or a fake controller though I don't have a spelling typo). The file it is referencing is input.inf & input.pnf, but those are default drivers, so I'm a little confused as to what to do, but maybe this is not the best place for this discussion. Can you direct me to a better place to discuss this?

Comment: I removed the driver ages ago and I'm afraid to screw things with my current driver. [MajorGeeks Forum](http://forums.majorgeeks.com/) is one of the best places to discuss drivers.

Comment: If you want to map your PS3 controller as an Xbox 360 controller, use [Xinput Wrapper](http://forums.pcsx2.net/Thread-XInput-Wrapper-for-DS3-and-Play-com-USB-Dual-DS2-Controller). This much better than MotionJoy because it replaces the PS3 driver, and there's no interface or adware involved. I'm using it right now.

Comment: That is exactly what I'm trying to do. switch from motionjoy to xinput but the driver won't detect the plugged in controller in this OS. Nm, I've given up on it now.

Comment: Link doesn't work and "Device Remover" isn't sufficiently distinct enough for an accurate Google hit

Comment: http://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/device_remover_543c.html